# How to access an object of another class

Tags: java, arrays, object

So I got this in a main program. As visible below I am first trying to edit the pay "45.0" by a raise of 10% of a single Employee object. Here I am making sure that my math calculation are correct. In another class I need to write a code to add the 10% to all the Employees.

`temp.obj.getData()` shows all the Employee data entered in the main class while the new object `e` is empty. Does someone know how I can get the data from the main program to object e or without creating object e. My problem is that when I am doing the same operations on object e the calculation of the pay are all 0. I think this is due to `pay = 0` . I seem to have a problem of getting the data (pay values ) from the objects in main class. Can someone help? Thanks if there is the need of more code ask me.

MAIN PROG:

```
            etemp[15] = new Employee(134, "Nicole", 45.0); 
            queue.put(etemp[15]);
            if(queue!=null){
                //Attempt 1  : Editing pay of a single employee
                System.out.println("not empty!");
                double x = etemp[15].getSalary();
                double calc = (x*0.10)+x;
                etemp[15].setPay(calc);
                System.out.println("Raise: "+etemp[15].getData());
                //Attempt 2 : Using a method to edit pay of ALL employee
                queue.pay(10);
            } else {
                System.out.println("empty");
            }
```

METHOD IN OTHER CLASS:

```
public void pay(int p){   
    int id = 0;
    String k = "";
    double pay = 0;        
    Employee e = new Employee(id, k, pay);
    CircQueue q = new CircQueue(20);
    if(rear!=null){
        Node temp=front;
        do{
            for (int i= 0; i<currNodes; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(temp.obj.getData()); 
                q.put(e);
                q.listAll();
                double x = e.getSalary();
                double calc = (x*0.10)+x;
                System.out.println("Raise: "+calc);
                temp = temp.next;
            }
        }while(!(temp==rear.next));
    } else System.out.println("Empty queue!");
}
```

Comment: Do you have an accessor/ getter method for 54.0, like getPay in the Employee object?

Comment: yes I have setSalary and getPay methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `this`method to pass your own instance as an argument. If I understood correctly, you need to use the `etemp` array in the other class, the one having the `pay` method. If that is right, you don't have to create more objects.

```
etemp[15] = new Employee(134, "Nicole", 45.0); 
            queue.put(etemp[15]);
            if(queue!=null){
                //Attempt 1  : Editing pay of a single employee
                System.out.println("not empty!");
                double x = etemp[15].getSalary();
                double calc = (x*0.10)+x;
                etemp[15].setPay(calc);
                System.out.println("Raise: "+etemp[15].getData());
                //Attempt 2 : Using a method to edit pay of ALL employee
                queue.pay(this,10); //Adding our own instance
            } else {
                System.out.println("empty");
            }
```

METHOD IN OTHER CLASS:

```
public void pay(MainClass m, int p){ 

    // Here you can use m as the instance, it will have the etemp. Normally, atributes are private, so you have to implement some kind of getters to reach to that array
    int id = 0;
    String k = "";
    double pay = m.getOriginalPay(id); // For example     
    Employee e = new Employee(id, k, pay);
    CircQueue q = new CircQueue(20);
    if(rear!=null){
        Node temp=front;
        do{
            for (int i= 0; i<currNodes; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(temp.obj.getData()); 
                q.put(e);
                q.listAll();
                double x = e.getSalary();
                double calc = (x*0.10)+x;
                System.out.println("Raise: "+calc);
                temp = temp.next;
            }
        }while(!(temp==rear.next));
    } else System.out.println("Empty queue!");
}
```

Tell me if I helped you.

Comment: yes, this makes sense I will be testing it out in a min will get back to you soon

Comment: It works!  This line double pay = m.getOriginalPay(id); just literally saved me thanks a lot